# Problema con petición POST en Angular

Tags: java, angular, spring

Quiero agregar un usuario-amigo, este es mi código de angular.

```
   import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListUserService {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/user/getUsers/`)
            .subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }

    getUsers() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/user/getUsers/';
        return this.http.get<Object[]>(url);
    }

    addFriend(user) {
        console.log('EEEEEE');
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/meet/friend';
        return this.http.post(url, {idOwner: user.id, userId: user.id});
    }
}
```

Pero solo obtengo error 400 ¿cual es el problema?

Este es mi endpoint.

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/friend/{idUser}/owner/{idOwner}",
            method = RequestMethod.POST
    )
    public ResponseEntity<Meet> friend(  @PathVariable Long idUser,@PathVariable Long idOwner) {
        log.info("PUSEN " +idOwner+"   "+idUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<Meet>(meetService.createMeetWithFriend(idOwner, idUser), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Ya probaste tu servicio rest de la siguiente forma http://localhost:8080/meet/friend/1/owner/1   en postman por ejemplo, los 1 representan {idUser} {idOwner}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El servidor te contestando con un error HTTP 400 Bad Request. Posiblemente sea por que le estas mandando parametros con nombres distintos a los que recibe tu endpoint. Intenta hacer la peticion de esta forma:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListUserService {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/user/getUsers/')
            .subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }

    getUsers() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/user/getUsers/';
        return this.http.get<Object[]>(url);
    }

    addFriend(user) {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/meet/friend/' + user.id + '/owner/' + user.id;
        return this.http.post(url);
    }
}
```

Y tu endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/friend/{idUser}/owner/{idOwner}",
        method = RequestMethod.POST
)
public ResponseEntity<Meet> friend(  @PathVariable Long idUser,@PathVariable Long idOwner) {
    log.info("PUSEN " +idOwner+"   "+idUser);
    return new ResponseEntity<Meet>(meetService.createMeetWithFriend(idOwner, idUser), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: sigo obteniendo el mismo error, ademas que no entra al log del backend

Comment: Puedes publicar un poco mas de tu codigo? creo que te esta faltando ponerle HttpHeaders a tu peticion. Algo como esto:

const config = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                                .set('Accept', 'application/json')

this.http.post('https://myapiserver', JSON.stringify(user), 
               { headers: config });

Comment: no entiendo donde debo poner el HttpHeaders

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, intenta hacer la modificacion que hice en el metodo addFriend() y en tu endpoint.

Comment: borre los requestBody y lo deje asi, public ResponseEntity<Meet> createMeetWithFriend( Long idOwner,  Long idUser) { y funciona, porque?

Comment: Si funciono al borrar @RequestParam("idOwner") y @RequestParam("idUser") puede ser que a tu endpoint no esten llegando los parametros idOwner, idUser que son enviados por tu aplicacion cliente. la anotacion @RequestParam indica que el parametro es obligatorio.

Comment: si tienes razon, llegan null

Comment: Puedes actualizar la pregunta con  el codigo que estas usando en este momento?

Comment: Creo que ya se cual puede ser tu problema:
return this.http.post(url, {"idOwner": user.id, "userId": user.id}, { headers: config }).subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });

Envia los nombres de los parametros encapulados en "" comillas.

Comment: sigue sin enviar datos, esto ya se volvio raro

Comment: el problema es el url, lo cambie /friend/{idUser}/owner/{idOwner} en el endpoint, pero no se como cambiarlo en el frontend

Comment: algo pasa cuando pongo asi: const url = 'http://localhost:8080/meet/friend/{}/owner/{}';

Comment: Y mí respuesta no sirve?, por lo que veo cambiaste la URL, más o menos como dije, ahora cuál es el problema que tenés en el front? Disculpa la pregunta

Answer (score 3):

Además del tema de los endpoints a mi parecer poco descriptivos y válidos para la operación que se desea realizar (arriba aclarado por otros miembros de la comunidad), te estaría faltando indicar en el método de tu controller el requestBody.

La anotación @RequestBody asigna el cuerpo HttpRequest a un objeto de dominio o transferencia, permitiendo la deserialización automática del cuerpo HttpRequest entrante en un objeto Java.

Aquí un ejemplo para que te puedas guiar:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/upcontact/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Contact> upContact(@RequestBody Contact contact) {
```

Answer (score 1):

no tengo NI IDEA de como funciona spring, ni http.post, y respondo esta pregunta sin animo de ofender o molestar, pero me gustaria saber, si @RequestParam de Spring, no esta pidiendo un parametro de la url como /friends?idOwner=Carlitos, y al pasarlo por el segundo parametro de http.post se esta enviando como el body

basicamente, me gustaria que pruebes con:
    const url = 'localhost:8080/meet/friend?idOwner='+user.id + '&userId='+userId;

Comment: eso seria peticion get